# Why does my engine hesitate when I first start?

Tags: engine, troubleshooting

My question may be related to [this other one](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/3565/437), but its answer is inadequate for me to be able to diagnose my problem and know what to do to fix it.

When I start my car in the morning (or sometimes after work if I work late), the car starts fine and idles normally. However, once I press the accelerator and pull out of my parking spot, the engine begins to run rough for 3-4 seconds. During this time, I have very little power/acceleration. Then, the engine smooths out, my power is restored, and all is fine until the next morning.

This problem has only recently started; there hasn't been any obvious trigger event, to the best of my knowledge.

What’s going on, and how can I fix it?

2003 Hyundai Elantra

Comment: Do you see different behavior in different weather?

Comment: Also, does it make any difference if you let the car sit and idle for a while (let the car warm-up)?

Comment: Scott, check the connection at the PCV valve/boot. I've had two oil changes where the boot was either left disconnected, or damaged and shoddily repaired (like with electrical tape O.o). In both cases, I didn't notice until the next day--something about a warm engine must soften the symptoms--and the first time I didn't consider it might have been something related to the oil change for a couple days. It's easy check, I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: and what's the odometer reading??

Comment: About 145k miles

Answer (score 1):

Injectors or spark plug leads (if not using coil packs). When was the last time u changed your plugs? 
Also check for tears in vacuum hoses. Though usually vacuum leaks symptoms wouldn't disappear.